# C++ equivalent to this GLSL functions

Tags: c++, glsl

Can somebody tell me what's the Cpp equivalent of this two GLSL functions is ?
(Component wise solution prefered).

```
vec4 pack( float v ) {
  vec4 enc = vec4(1.0, 255.0, 65025.0, 160581375.0) * v;
  enc = fract(enc);
  enc -= enc.yzww * vec4(1.0/255.0,1.0/255.0,1.0/255.0,0.0);
  return enc;
}


float unpack( vec4 rgba ) {
  return dot( rgba, vec4(1.0, 1/255.0, 1/65025.0, 1/160581375.0) );
}
```

Source: [Source of the code above](http://aras-p.info/blog/2009/07/30/encoding-floats-to-rgba-the-final/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really is not that difficult if you know how all the built-ins work. `fract (...)` returns the fractional part of a floating-point number and the dot product is just the component-wise sum of products.

#### The only unusual thing is the `yzww` swizzle, but that is easy to accomplish:

```
// C++ offers `modf (...)`, which does the same thing, but this is simpler.
float fract (float f) {
  return f-(long)f;
}

void pack (float v, float* enc) {
  enc [0] = fract (1.0f         * v);
  enc [1] = fract (255.0f       * v);
  enc [2] = fract (65025.0f     * v);
  enc [3] = fract (160581375.0f * v);

  enc [0] -= enc [1] * 1.0f/255.0f;
  enc [1] -= enc [2] * 1.0f/255.0f;
  enc [2] -= enc [3] * 1.0f/255.0f;

  return enc;
}

float unpack (const float* rgba) {
  float dot = rgba [0] * 1.0f               +  rgba [1] * (1.0f / 255.0f)  +
              rgba [2] * (1.0f / 65025.0f)  +  rgba [3] * (1.0f / 160581375.0f);
  return dot;
}
```

I took the liberty of changing `pack (...)` to accept an array where it stores its result instead of returning an array on the stack. It is the more common practice in C, but if you had some C++ class you used to store 4D vectors you could return an instance of that instead.

All of this could be made a lot simpler if you used the GLM template library. It mirrors GLSL's types and operators as closely as possible in C++.